# Find all possible paths in a python graph data structure without using recursive function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion, graph-theory

I have a serious issue with finding all possible paths in my csv file that looks like this :

| Source | Target | Source_repo | Target_repo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SOURCE1 | Target2 | repo-1 | repo-2 |
| SOURCE5 | Target3 | repo-5 | repo-3 |
| SOURCE8 | Target5 | repo-8 | repo-5 |

There a large amount of lines in the datasets, more than 5000 lines. I want to generate all possible paths like this in and return a list (Target5 is equal to SOURCE5):

- SOURCE1 Target2
- SOURCE8 Target5 Target3

I want to implement this solution without using recursive functions, since causes problems (maximum recursion depth exceeded).

This is the current code example :

```
def attach_co_changing_components(base_component):
    co_changes = df_depends_on.loc[df_depends_on["Source_repo"] ==
                                   base_component, "Target_repo"].values
    result = {base_component: list(co_changes)}
    return result


def dfs(data, path, paths):
    datum = path[-1]
    if datum in data:
        for val in data[datum]:
            new_path = path + [val]
            paths = dfs(data, new_path, paths)
    else:
        paths += [path]
    return paths



def enumerate_paths(graph, nodes=[]):
    nodes = graph.keys()
    all_paths = []
    for node in nodes:
        node_paths = dfs(graph, [node], [])
        all_paths += node_paths
    return all_paths


if __name__ == "__main__":

    df = pd.read_csv("clean_openstack_evolution.csv")

    co_changing_components = df[["Source"]].copy()

    co_changing_components = co_changing_components.drop_duplicates(
    ).reset_index(drop=True)

    co_changing_components = co_changing_components["Source"].map(
        attach_co_changing_components)

    co_changing_components = co_changing_components.rename("Path")

    co_changing_components = co_changing_components.reset_index(drop=True)

    newdict = {}
    for k, v in [(key, d[key]) for d in co_changing_components for key in d]:
        if k not in newdict: newdict[k] = v
        else: newdict[k].append(v)

    graph_keys = df_depends_on["Source_repo"].drop_duplicates().to_dict(
    ).values()
    graph_keys = {*graph_keys}
    graph_keys = set([
        k for k in graph_keys
        if len(df_depends_on[df_depends_on["Target"] == k]) > 0
    ])

    result = enumerate_paths(new_dict)
```

Here is the output after executing the preceding code :

[image: Result of the preceding code]

Here is the data link [Google drive](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kl3jgRIHCKtEatug2YAZ1As0Z4zAoAAb/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102737873479084956825&rtpof=true&sd=true)

I tried to solve the problem using recursive function, but the code failed with the problem of depth exceeded. I aim to solve it without recursive functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want *all* paths or paths specifically from node to another node. Either way this looks like a job for [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/).

## Setup ([`nx.from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html))

```py
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("...")

graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
```

## All paths ([`nx.all_simple_paths`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html#networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths))

```py
from itertools import chain, product, starmap
from functools import partial


roots = (node for node, d in graph.in_degree if d == 0)

leaves = (node for node, d in graph.out_degree if d == 0)

all_paths = partial(nx.all_simple_paths, graph)

paths = list(chain.from_iterable(starmap(all_paths, product(roots, leaves))))
```

## From one node to another

```py
source_node = "some_node_in_graph"
target_node = "some_other_node_in_graph"
list(nx.all_simple_paths(graph, source=source_node, target=target_node))
```

Comment: That's a great answer. It solved the problem I encountered. I appreciate your help

Comment: @AliArabat glad I could help. If it answers your Q please consider selecting it as the answer :)